# End UNWIND statement in a Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have a cypher query that unwinds a parameter, everything after that portion of the query is called x number of times of the unwind. I'd like to figure out a way to end the unwind and continue with other things.

```
MATCH (thing:Thing)
UNWIND { names } AS name
CREATE thing-[:HAS_NAME]-(n:Name {name: name})
//done with the unwind
WITH (thing)
CREATE thing[:HAS_AGE]-(a:Age {age: 20})
```

In the above example, I will end up with two thing-[:HAS_AGE]->() relationships because of the unwind. Do I have to split this into separate statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the unwind you have two rows.  If you re-collapse `thing` before moving on you will then have a single again.

```
MATCH (thing:Thing)
UNWIND { names } AS name
CREATE thing-[:HAS_NAME]-(n:Name {name: name})
//done with the unwind
WITH distinct thing
CREATE thing[:HAS_AGE]-(a:Age {age: 20})
```

Comment: awesome! So if I needed to use multiple WITH items could I say: WITH a, b, distinct c, d, e   to just collapse the things that were expanded?

Comment: Yes, `WITH` is an incredibly powerful statement in cypher.  It allows you to collect, unwind, recollect in between clauses of your query. An alternate approach in this case might be to create the age relationship prior to the unwind statement.