# Chain UNWIND in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to use two lists to create nodes/relationships in cypher. Using the solution for [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744331/end-unwind-statement-in-a-cypher-query), my current solution is:

```
MERGE (t:Test)
WITH t
UNWIND ["a","b"] AS name                      // first list
MERGE (t)-[:FOO_REL]->(a:Foo { name: name })
WITH DISTINCT t
UNWIND [100,200] AS id                        // second list
MERGE (t)-[:BAR_REL]->(b:Bar { id: id })
```

This works as long as both lists have entries in them. However, if the first list is empty then the second list is never unwound (and no `:Bar` nodes are created).

How would I go about chaining `UNWIND`s such that I can create nodes/relationships from two separate lists in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [`FOREACH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/) instead of `UNWIND`. Since this uses parentheses around the inner query, they are clearly delimited from eachother:

```
MERGE (t:Test)
FOREACH (name in ["a","b"] | 
  MERGE (t)-[:FOO_REL]->(a:Foo { name: name })
)
FOREACH (id in [100,200] |
  MERGE (t)-[:BAR_REL]->(b:Bar { id: id })
)
```